# CSS styling : change colour of <blockquote> between posts?

Tags: html, css, web

I've got a theme in which the `blockquote` tag takes on the following style through CSS

```
{background-color:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%,#F5FBEF), color-stop(50%,#E0F8E0), color-stop(51%,#E6F8E0), 
color-stop(100%,#F5FBEF)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #E0FFE8 12%, #E0FFE7 30%, 
#E5FFEC 49%, #EAFCED 70%, #F5FFF7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */;
border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:auto;padding-left:0.9em;
padding-right:0.9em;white-space:pre-wrap;} /* #page */ 
#page{margin:1.8em 2.4em 3.6em 2.4em;}
```

such that a quoted section of text can be rendered distinctly, as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

This gets a little plain over the course of a page though, on which several posts will share these green sections (http://biochemistri.es). Is there a way I can alternate between say green and blue between posts? I might have multiple such `blockquote` tags within a post but wouldn't want to alternate their colour within a single post - might look a bit messy.

I'd like to think I could implement this with CSS, I've used nth-child tags and the like before... It seems simple enough but I've no idea how to do it with code for posts in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`nth-child`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) pseudo selector to select even or odd elements. That way you can add some overrides for those.

```
blockquote:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This won't work in IE8-, but hey, maybe they can live with just a single color. ;-)

[edit]

After reading @DrydenLong's comment and then re-reading your question, I see you want to alternate blockquotes between posts, not alternate them within a post.

That will need a sligtly different selector. You can start with the `post` class, which every post seems to have:

```
.post:nth-child(even) blockquote { /* overrides go here */ }
```

But in your html code, I can see that odd posts also have a class `post_odd` and even posts have `post_even`, so you might as well use that as a selector:

```
.post blockquote { /* Defaults go here */ }
.post.post_even blockquote { /* Overrides go here */ }
```

The disadvantage of any of these solutions, is that it will not check whether a post contains a blockquote at all. So, two posts might both show a green blockquote if there is a small, quote-less post inbetween. I assume that won't be a big problem, but if it is you will probably need to add quite some logic, either in the page generation procedure or using Javascript/JQuery. I'd say it's not worth it. :)

Comment: +1 since you beat me to it, but wouldn't OP need to make adjustments in order to keep this from alternating colors within a single post? Without OP's HTML markup I couldn't say for sure though

Comment: Cooool, thanks you 2, yeah this makes sense. I just checked my source code and post_odd and post_even are actually already in the CSS! If I implemented it through this then actually it'd just colour the two sides of the page differently, so I might use .post_even blockquote:nth-child(even) etc. to give 4, so as to be a bit more effective in breaking the page up rather than merely emphasising the columns. Was just a thought but definitely gna prototype it now, thanks again :)

Comment: Re: that last edit you just made, I put blockquote elements in most of the posts as they're usually regarding a recent paper, and if I had the 4 slightly different hues as described above any post missing a blockquote element wouldn't make so great a difference. Will just have to try and make it subtle if I'll use it or else might clutter things. Cheers

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks! I wasn't sure exactly how to handle it since I didn't actually check out his/her site... Good catch on the classes too